# Data Validation - do while loop

Tags: java, validation, loops

I am having trouble with validation of String input. I want  to make it so that the user cannot enter an invalid String (only "CIS 280", "ACC 201", "CIS 120", "CIS 185"). However, I cannot figure out how to do it with strings.

**My problems are**

1. When I enter a valid input, the program exits and does not display the corresponding time.
2. when I enter a invalid input in the first input dialog, the program then enters an infinite loop, even when I enter a valid String at:

   ```
   invalid = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a valid class.");
   ```

```
public class arraytest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        String classInput;
        boolean valid = false;
        String invalid;
        String[][] classNames = {
          {"CIS 280", "ACC 201", "CIS 120", "CIS 185"},
          {"Tue 5:00", "Mon & Weds 12:20", "Mon & Weds 10:10", "Mon & Weds 12:00" }
        };
        classInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a class name: ");

        do {
            for (i = 0; i < classNames[0].length; ++i) {
                if(classNames[0][i].equals(classInput)) {
                    valid = true;
                }
            }
            if(valid == false) {
                invalid = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a valid class.");
                classInput.equals(invalid);
            }
        } while(valid == false);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The time of that class is: " + classNames[1][i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? How does it "not work"?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
get users input
do{
   validate input
   if input is wrong ask again //btw here is your error, 
                               //check where you are storing user's input
}while(input is wrong)
```

try

```
do{
   get users input
   validate input
}while(input is wrong)
```

---

Another thing is that you are iterating till end of row which will make `i` equal of `length` of row. You need to stop iterating when you will find correct value so you could use this `i` in your

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The time of that class is: " + classNames[1][i]);
```